# Grafana DataSource created with ''Pattern'' = No Pattern in elasticsearch.yml datasources config file

Tags: openshift, grafana, grafana-templating, configmap

I am installing Grafana in OpenShift and want to put all our DataSources in a ConfigMap( I can't use the GUI).

So far, it all work's good, my config map is being read and Grafana is happy with it. Sort of... I need more...

In (GUI) the 'Elastisearch Details' section, It does not fill the ''Pattern'' field that I think is related to the ''interval'' field in the YAML version of it. At least, if I specify ''No pattern", it does nothing, however, If i put "Hourly" it does apply it as a value.

So I'm confused here. It that a bug ? Do I need to escape the space in ''No pattern'' ( I did try with a back slash) ? I did try a empty value, etc...

Help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a bug in the interface. The null value is taken in account, however, it does not show in the GUI.

See this thread on Grafana GitHub.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12281